# `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` Threads are not killed after execution in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to change Quartz Sequential execution to Parallel Execution.

It is working fine, Performance wise, it is seems good but Spawned (created) threads are not destroyed.

It is Still in `Runnable` State; why and How can I fix that?
Please Guide me.

[image]

Code is here :

```
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.error("Result Processing executed");
        List<Object[]> lstOfExams = examService.getExamEntriesForProcessingResults();
        String timeZone = messageService.getMessage("org.default_timezone", null, Locale.getDefault());
        if(lstOfExams!=null&&!lstOfExams.isEmpty()){
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecuter = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            threadPoolExecuter.setCorePoolSize(lstOfExams.size());
            threadPoolExecuter.setMaxPoolSize(lstOfExams.size()+1);
            threadPoolExecuter.setBeanName("ThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
            threadPoolExecuter.setQueueCapacity(100);
            threadPoolExecuter.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadForUpdateExamResult");
            threadPoolExecuter.initialize();

            for(Object[] obj : lstOfExams){
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank((String)obj[2]) ){
                    timeZone = obj[2].toString();
                }
                try {
                    Userexams userexams=examService.findUserExamById(Long.valueOf(obj[0].toString()));
                    if(userexams.getExamresult()==null){
                        UpdateUserExamDataThread task=new UpdateUserExamDataThread(obj,timeZone);
                        threadPoolExecuter.submit(task);
                    }
//                  testEvaluator.generateTestResultAsPerEvaluator(Long.valueOf(obj[0].toString()), obj[4].toString(), obj[3]==null?null:obj[3].toString(),timeZone ,obj[5].toString() ,obj[1].toString()); 
//                  logger.error("Percentage Marks:::::"+result.getPercentageCatScore());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.error("Exception at ResultProcessingJob extends QuartzJobBean executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException",e);
                    continue;
                }

            }
            threadPoolExecuter.shutdown();
        }
}
```

UpdateUserExamDataThread .class

```
@Component
//@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
//public class UpdateUserExamDataThread extends ThreadLocal<String> //implements Runnable {
public class UpdateUserExamDataThread implements Runnable {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UpdateUserExamDataThread.class);
    @Autowired
    ExamService examService;
    @Autowired
    TestEvaluator testEvaluator;
    private Object[] obj;
    private String timeZone;


    public UpdateUserExamDataThread(Object[] obj,String timeZone) {
        super();
        this.obj = obj;
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String threadName=String.valueOf(obj[0]);
        log.info("UpdateUserExamDataThread Start For:::::"+threadName);
        testEvaluator.generateTestResultAsPerEvaluator(Long.valueOf(obj[0].toString()), obj[4].toString(), obj[3]==null?null:obj[3].toString(),timeZone ,obj[5].toString() ,obj[1].toString());
        //update examResult
        log.info("UpdateUserExamDataThread End For:::::"+threadName);
    }

}
```

TestEvaluatorImpl.java

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Examresult generateTestResultAsPerEvaluator(Long userExamId, String evaluatorType, String codingLanguage,String timeZoneFollowed ,String inctenceId ,String userId) {
        dbSchema = messageService.getMessage("database.default_schema", null, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
//Some Methods
return examResult;
}catch(Exception e){
log.erorr(e);
}
}
```

I can provide Thread Dump file if needed.

Comment: may you post also UpdateUserExamDataThread code?

Comment: Also `TestEvaluator` please. We just need to make sure that the tasks actually end.

Comment: Also note that `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor .shutdown()` by default does not wait for the tasks to complete.

Comment: Hi I am Using Spring and there is configuration for waiting.
threadPoolExecuter.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
thanks for indicating.

Comment: Please up vote this question so that i can increase the bounty. I am low on points and reputation.

Comment: What is in your log file? Do the "UpdateUserExamDataThread End For:::::" messages appear there?

Comment: examId as the thread name has been taken for personal reference but for end there is no log and for start there is log.

Comment: Looking at the monitor, all your threads are stuck at the same line (line 37 of the `UpdateUserExamDataThread` class). Without a full listing of this class it'll be impossible for us to tell you why they're stuck. I also think you've omitted some code from that run method and replaced it with the "update examResult" comment. Ironically, I suspect that the omitted part contains the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Needed to increase the priority of threads and create number of threads as per number of cores in processor.

```
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.error("Result Processing executed");
        List<Object[]> lstOfExams = examService.getExamEntriesForProcessingResults();
        String timeZone = messageService.getMessage("org.default_timezone", null, Locale.getDefault());
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if(lstOfExams!=null&&!lstOfExams.isEmpty()){
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecuter = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            threadPoolExecuter.setCorePoolSize(cores);
//          threadPoolExecuter.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            threadPoolExecuter.setBeanName("ThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
//          threadPoolExecuter.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            threadPoolExecuter.setQueueCapacity(lstOfExams.size()+10);
            threadPoolExecuter.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadForUpdateExamResult");
            threadPoolExecuter.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
            threadPoolExecuter.setThreadPriority(10);
            threadPoolExecuter.initialize();


            for(Object[] obj : lstOfExams){
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank((String)obj[2]) ){
                    timeZone = obj[2].toString();
                }
                try {
                    Userexams userexam=examService.findUserExamById(Long.valueOf(obj[0].toString()));
                    if(userexam.getExamresult()==null){
                        UpdateUserExamDataThread task=new UpdateUserExamDataThread(obj,timeZone,testEvaluator);
//                      threadPoolExecuter.submit(task);
                        threadPoolExecuter.execute(task);
                    }
//                  testEvaluator.generateTestResultAsPerEvaluator(Long.valueOf(obj[0].toString()), obj[4].toString(), obj[3]==null?null:obj[3].toString(),timeZone ,obj[5].toString() ,obj[1].toString()); 
//                  logger.error("Percentage Marks:::::"+result.getPercentageCatScore());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception at ResultProcessingJob extends QuartzJobBean executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException",e);
                    continue;
                }
            }
                threadPoolExecuter.shutdown();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

it seems you create a thread pool in the same size of exams which is not quite optimal.

```
    // Core pool size is = number of exams  
    threadPoolExecuter.setCorePoolSize(lstOfExams.size());

    // Max pool size is just 1 + exam size. 
    threadPoolExecuter.setMaxPoolSize(lstOfExams.size()+1);
```

You have to consider that:
- If you create a thread pool and started it as many threads as defined in core size started immediately.

- The max pool size is only than effective when you submit more than core pool threads can process right now AND when the queue size is full (in this case 100). So that means a new thread will be only then created when the number of submitted tasks exceeded 100+exam size.

In your case I would set the core pool size 5 or 10 (it actually depends on the how many core your target CPU have and/or how IO bound the submitted tasks are).

The max pool size can be double of that but it doesn't effective until the queue is full.

To let the size of live threads decrease after the submitted work done you have to set 2 parameters.

- **setKeepAliveSeconds(int keepAliveSeconds)** : Which let the threads shut down automatically if they are not used along the defined seconds (by default 60 seconds, which is optimal) BUT this is normally only used to shut down threads of non-core pool threads.
- To shut down threads of core part after keepAliveSeconds you have to set **setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean allowCoreThreadTimeOut)** as true. Which is normally false to keep core pool alive as long as the application is running.

I hope it helps.

Comment: hi with your recommendation i have came up with few solution that are really helping me, and set 
threadPoolExecuter.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
threadPoolExecuter.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 to default value ie
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
threadPoolExecuter.setCorePoolSize(cores);
threadPoolExecuter.setThreadPriority(10);
and Rather than submit i am using 
threadPoolExecuter.execute(task);
After that Those threads are not in Runnable State.

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't set the max pool size with Integer.MAX_VALUE. This can be dangerous and not really effective. Since your OS already limits the number of max threads the number of MAX_VALUE threads will not be reached. I would set the max pool size maximum as twice as the core pool size. The queue capacity can be relative high, according to the size of the submitted tasks, but again MAX_VALUE is far too high.

Comment: By default it is MAX_VALUE so I haven't overwritten it is managed by spring and jvm and it is doing good, but it can be dangerous .

Comment: Oh yes now I see. IF both maxPoolSize and maxQueueCapacity set as MAX_VALUE, the pool would not expand the core size. Thus actually there is no danger in this combination. But when the queue size is limited with a small number then the max pool size should also limited with a really small value.

Comment: Yes it will be waste of resources.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that one of your threads waits indefinitely for an IO request answer. For example, you try to connect to a remote host where you did not set connection timeout and the host does not answer. In this case, you can shutdown all executing tasks forcefully by running `shutdownNow` method of the underlying `ExecutorService` then you can analyze [InterruptedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) thrown by the offending threads.

Replace

```
threadPoolExecuter.shutdown();
```

with below so you can examine errors.

```
ExecutorService executorService = threadPoolExecuter.getThreadPoolExecutor();
executorService.shutdownNow();
```

This will send [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) signal to all running threads.

Answer (score 0):

The threads do not wait on IO from some remote server, because the executed method on the threads would be in some jdbc driver classes, but they are currently all in UpdateUserExamDataThread.run(), line 37.

Now the question is: what is the code at UpdateUserExamDataThread.java line 37 ?
Unfortunately, the UpdateUserExamDataThread.java given at the moment is incomplete and/or not the version really executed: the package declaration is missing and it ends at line 29.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is simply that you are calling run() instead of execute() when spawning the task thread using submit(). There is probably some expectation when using submit that threads kill themselves when the task is finished rather than terminating at the end of the run method.